# Why is there a white border in a footer div?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a div in footer from side by side, but with this code it is leaving a white border.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #bottomnav {
                background-color: #333;
                opacity: 1;
                height: 100px;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                overflow: visible;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <footer>
        <div id="bottomnav">
              Hello
        </div>
    </footer>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [I don't see one](http://jsfiddle.net/gJJLQ/).

Comment: Did you try a CSS reset? Have you managed to replicate the problem in a Fiddle?

Comment: @showdev: I still don't see one.

Comment: Which browser are you testing this in? try `html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0 }`. Or as suggested by others, use a CSS reset or normalizer.

Comment: Problem: http://jsfiddle.net/w5Aha/2/ Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/w5Aha/1/

Comment: @showdev: Ah, I see it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description, I can't tell quite what problem you have, but I'm guessing it's the margin on the `body` element. Try this:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset `body` margins to zero.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to clear the body margins

```
* {margin:0; padding:0;}
```

but universal selectors can affect you page load times

Have a look at css resets and what the various fixes can do for your browser

http://www.cssreset.com/

also this may explain a bunch of things for you http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/04/18/reset-reasoning/